# P/Invoke a purely C++ library?

Tags: .net, c++, pinvoke

Is it possible to P/Invoke a pure C++ library, or does it have to be wrapped in C?

Comment: Look at this CodeProject article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/usingcppdll.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ libraries can be P/invoked, but you'll need to use "depends" to find the mangled method names (names like "@0!classname@classname@zz") and for instance methods use "ThisCall" calling convention in the p/invoke and pass the reference of the instance as the first argument (you can store the result of the constructor within an IntPtr).

Comment: Another alternative is C++/CLI.

Comment: This is terrible advice.  Even if it's technically possible, you'll run into many MANY problems trying to p/invoke into C++ classes.  For example, constructors and destructors won't be called properly, .NET memory handling isn't compatible with C++ `new` and `delete`, and so on.  C++/CLI is a much much better idea.

Comment: The question was how to PInvoke which I answered. The create/delete issues can easily be overcome by find static create and delete methods to the C++ and calling them from the wrapping C# class.

Comment: @DannyVarod  Your answer is indeed correct. The major differences between a C++ class method(non-pure-virtual-method, non-static-method) call and a C-style call are just what you have mentioned, 1. Mangled name, 2. Calling convention of "ThisCall" 3. Passing the reference of the instance as the first argument. I have written a tool to automate that. [PInvoke Interop SDK](http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2013/04/13/introduction-to-c-pinvoke-interop-sdk/)

Comment: Instead of usind `depends` to get the mangled name, you can also use `dumpbin /exports <...>.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

A "pure" C++ library will have its name mangled by the compiler, so it will be hard to get the P/Invoke declaration correct.
And a C method gets an underscore at the beginning, which may not be there in C++.
And a C++ method needs a this instance as a first parameter, you'd have to give it yourself.

I think that you need to wrap your C++ API in a C-compatible series of methods.

Comment: Only an instance method of an object takes an implicit `this`.

Comment: Of course, but I can't imagine a C++ library using only static methods.

Comment: C++ allows non-member methods too, you know.

Comment: @jalf, yes, I agree with you, as well as with 280Z28. But, and I apologize for insisting, can you imagine writing a C++ library and using only non-member methods ?

Comment: Yes. I can imagine a C++ library which uses member methods internally, but whose public interface is all non-member functions. Still, I agree with your point: Typical C++ libraries do expose member methods are part of their interface.

Comment: C++ methods have to be passed `this`, but the calling convention is not simply "put it into the first parameter".

Comment: @jalf: Normally the word "method" implies a non-static member.  Others are called *functions* instead.

Comment: @Ben true, and if we want to be pedantic, C++ doesn't even *have* methods (the standard refers to member *functions*, not methods). I'm not sure why I said methods. I guess I was trying to use the same terminology as the answer I commented on.

Comment: @jalf: I know that, but *method* is a well-defined computer science term in the area of OOP, and in that sense C++ definitely does have them (although possibly only *virtual* member functions qualify).  Just like C++ definitely has implementation inheritance, although the standard calls this a "derived class".